# How to split by "" in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, split

So, I need to change a string e.g. `STRING` and change it into `['S', 'T', 'R', 'I', 'N', 'G']`

So far, I've tried the following:
`o.split('')` and `o.split()`
how would I go about doing this?

Comment: `list("STRING")`

Comment: For most intents and purposes, a string is already a list of characters and can be treated as such. Why do you need to split it…?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple, as follows:

```
my_str = 'STRING'
chars = list(my_str)
```